# Dependencies not included

Tags: python, package

I created a new package called `hashnode-py` and included some requirements, but when I run `pip install hashnode-py` it just install hashnode-py without requirements

**requirements.txt:**

```
gql
requests
```

**setup.py:**

```
`import setuptools

about = {}
with open("hashnode_py/__about__.py") as fp:
    exec(fp.read(), about)

with open("requirements.txt") as f:
    requirements = f.read().splitlines()

with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

setuptools.setup(
    name=about['__title__'],
    version=about['__version__'],
    url=about['__github__'],
    license=about['__license__'],
    author=about['__author__'],
    author_email=about['__email__'],
    description=about['__description__'],
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    classifiers=(
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ),
    python_requires=">=3.11",
    dev_requires=[
        "pytest>=8.0", "twine>=4.0.2"
    ],
    requires=requirements
)
```

also here is a link of my repo [here](https://github.com/TalaatHasanin/hashnode_py).

I tried some solutions but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `install_requires=requirements`, not `requires=requirements`.

From [setuptools keywords](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/references/keywords.html)

> requires is superseded by install_requires and should not be used
> anymore.